# Как суммировать время php или js?

Tags: php, jquery

Здравствуйте, есть массив:

array(4) {
  
[0]=>
  
string(8) "00:05:23"
  
[1]=>
  
string(8) "06:23:00"
  
[2]=>
  
string(8) "05:00:00"
  
[3]=>
  
string(8) "05:40:00"

}

Получаю его и з базы таким способом:

```
$getAllTime = $db->query("SELECT * FROM `wt_action` WHERE user_id = '$id'");
$time = [];
foreach ($getAllTime as $i) {
    $time[] = $i['summ_work_time'];
}
```

Как мне суммировать все это в время ? Или на php или в javascript.

Тоесть мне надо суммировать вот это время:

00:05:23

06:23:00

05:00:00

05:40:00

= 17:08:23

p.s. массив будет пополнятся новым временем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно преобразовать часы и минуты в секуды, потом сложить эти суммы между собой, а после - вычислить сумму всех секунд в массиве *$time*, и передать эту сумму в конструктор класса *DateTime*

```
$time = [ 
    '00:05:23',
    '06:23:00',
    '05:00:00',
    '05:40:00'
];

$time = array_map(function($t) {
    [$h, $i, $s] = explode(':', $t);
    return ($h*3600) + ($i*60) + $s;
}, $time);

$timestamp = array_sum($time);
$time = new DateTime("@$timestamp");

echo $time->format('H:i:s');
```

Результат:

```
17:08:23
```